# jQuery: How do I find specific input type, it's id/name and then the <td> holding it and toggle it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I toggle the check-boxes and their display text upon clicking the text "click to display"?

**my code:** Edit - this is how the actual code appears in the app -

```
 <td class="txtval"><input type="checkbox" name="798[]" id="798[]" value="1" 0="txtval" 1="" style="display: inline-block;">Yes
<td class="txtval"><input type="checkbox" name="798[]" id="798[]" value="1" 0="txtval" 1="" style="display: inline-block;">No
<td class="txtval"><input type="checkbox" name="798[]" id="798[]" value="1" 0="txtval" 1="" style="display: inline-block;">Maybe</td></tr>
```

**How do find the input type checkbox with the name 798[], then find the previous  and toggle it**

Comment: where's your JavaScript? jQuery simply uses `.toggle()`

Comment: What's with the `"0="` at the end of your `value` attributes? The zero should either be in single quotes or you should escape the quotes using `\"`

Comment: what change do you want in the display text

Comment: You may also want to change `Fruits: [click to display]` to `Fruits: <span class="toggle-ckb">[click to display]</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make clicking on the text toggle display of the checkboxes:

```
$('tr td:first').on("click", function()
                    {
                        $(this).next().toggle();
                    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pq7tK/3/

In your comment you ask: *"How can I do this: find the input type checkbox with the name 798[], then find the previous td and toggle it"*

My guess is you want this:

```
$('input[name='798[]']).closest('td').toggle();
```

Comment: Plynx - I like this idea - my code was sample.  I posted the actual code string above. - How can I do this:  find the input type checkbox with the name 798[], then find the previous td and toggleit

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
$("input[name='7365[]']").attr("checked", "checked")
```

BTW. ID attribute values should be unique for each element.

Comment: I think he just wanted to display or hide the group of checkboxes...but anyway, I just wanted to add that the recommended way of checking a checkbox in jQuery is now `.prop('checked', true);`...the jQuery documentation for `prop()` explains why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to toggle : [Toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMapR/1/)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
              this.checked = !this.checked;
    });
```

Comment: Or you can use `this.checked = !this.checked` without any `if /else`

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Fruits: <a href="javascript:;" id="lnkClickToDisplay">[click to display]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
        <td id="checkboxesContainer" style="display:none">
            <input type="checkbox" name="7365[]" id="7365[]" value="orange"0="">orange<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="7365[]" id="7365[]" value="apples"0="">apples<br /><input type="checkbox" name="7365[]" id="7365[]" value="pears"0="">pears<br />                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>

$(function() {
    $('#lnkClickToDisplay').click(function() {
        $('#checkboxesContainer').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
$('tr td:eq(1)').hide();

$('tr').on('click', '.toggler', function(e){
    var ct = $(e.currentTarget);
    if(ct.is('.items-hidden')){
        ct.html('click to display').removeClass('items-hidden');
    } else {
        ct.html('click to hide').addClass('items-hidden');
    }
    ct.parent().next().toggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pq7tK/4/)